# Reaching 40-Vote Limit Closes Some Queues, Not Others

Tags: discussion

Today, I used all forty of my allotted votes and then found that the First Posts and Late Answers queues were closed to me for the rest of the day.  Why these two and not the other four?

Comment: I don't *know* but I shall guess: a reasonable action on both First Posts and Late Answers is to vote, either up or down.  Showing these queue items therefore while voting is not possible might not be appropriate.  However for e.g. the Close Votes queue the more important action is to either vote to close or leave open, and since the close votes are independent from the question votes (I believe) this would still be possible.  The answer to your question is probably on [Meta.SE] but I am apparently terrible at searching that site so I'll leave it to someone else.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149669/209088) on meta.se  corresponds to your guess.

Comment: And so does [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147516/209088)

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino  The second link posted by Jacob Akkerboom is informative, although I do not agree with its conclusions.  I have no answer myself.  Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Running out of up/down votes locks you out of First Posts and Late Answers queues
- Running out of close votes locks you out of Close queue
- Running out of reopen votes locks you out of Reopen queue (I think; this never actually happened to me, unlike the situation with the Close queue).

The logic is the same in each case: if a user is unable to perform some of the primary functions of the queue, they are asked to defer to another user who can.

First Posts and Late Answers invite voting up or down. All other queues **disable** voting up or down; they invite other actions.